Police action '90s movie: an addict cop with a lesbian partner
It's a long time I haven't been able to find a movie I've seen in the early/mid '90s.
It was a police/action movie, where the protagonist was actually able to do all the action cool stuff because he was an addict to some sort of stimulant, and his partner was a lesbian.
It struck me because it was the first time in such a movie where the "almost-superhuman" abilities of the main character, instead of being taken for granted, are explained because he was basically cheating with drugs, and I thought this was quite original. Also the presence of a lesbian partner will likely narrow it down enough, hopefully.
(the only detail left is that I've watched it in Italian, though I strongly doubt there is a movie which matches all of the above, but just not this last detail)

(obviously I've tried to google for it several times, but always failed)

It sounds very similar to the 1988 movie Arizona Heat. Michael Parks plays a tough cop teamed up with a lesbian partner played by Denise Crosby.
The trailer is here. While there is nothing in the IMDb synopsis or trailer about drugs, it is worth noting that the music playing in the background of the trailer is Steppenwolf's "The Pusher," a song about drugs.
I know you said 90's but this seemed a good fit and only 2 years off.

Might be it! I'll have a look, thanks : ) Since I've seen it in the '90s, 1988 as production date seems quite likely!
